# create a calendar event based on a columns from other list? in Modern Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, events

I've created a list that the user can add an item and insert some informations about a employees conferences. On that list there is a columns that is called "About the events", "Title", "Start date", "End Date" and Link.  I would like to know if it is possible to create a Calendar that reflects all the dates and titles based on this other list column.

Comment: Yes it is possible, look into this plugin to handle rendering calendar events - https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: @Matt. L , Can you Clarify a little bit more Please ?

Comment: Sure, FullCalendar is real easy to work with with SharePoint lists. It's very easy to read in data from your list, and apply it into event objects in FullCalendar. It has built in accepts for Title, StartDate, EndDate, etc. and provides plenty of room for extra properties you define, like "about" and some links